# "Нарочно чтобы" - с запятой, без?

Tags: пунктуация, спп

> С тревогой рассматривали из-за кулис, как рассаживаются в зале наши
>   строгие критики. Они ведь пришли нарочно, чтоб обличать!

В смысле - специально, с целью (чтобы)? Как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Они ведь пришли нарочно, чтоб обличать!**

В данном случае наречие и придаточное раскрывают одну тему, придаточное **уточняет цель**, поэтому запятая ставится.

НАРОЧНО , нареч. 1. С целью, с определённым намерением (обычно вопреки желанию кого-л.);

Я это делал **нарочно, чтобы** вызвать в ее душе определенный взрыв и направить его тут же в русло роли. [Эльдар Рязанов. Подведенные итоги (2000)]

И еще 200 примеров из Нацкорпуса (популярная конструкция).

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна в любом случае, составного союза «нарочно(,) чтобы» нет. Здесь «нарочно» наречие, оно характеризует глагол «пришли» и относится к главной части сложноподчиненного предложения с союзом «чтобы».

Ср.: Ты что, нарошно пришла, чтобы сделать мне больно?!